# GAE - unable to fetch URL from BigQuery API

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-bigquery, oauth2client

Our integration platform now gets couple of "Unable to fetch URL: ..." errors everyday. I don't know what's the cause of this.

First GAE tries to authorize with OAuth2 from within application to BigQuery through the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/). it tries in every second for more than 30 seconds (that's just 1 of 30 similar lines):

```
2015-05-12 05:59:02.727
URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/XXX/jobs/job_w-z5K2zQObXeSaLy3hx7m4FOMXc?alt=json
```

Below is trace itself (just after logs presented above):

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXX/processes:uno.383135852015228853/connectors/connector_XXX_v1_0.py", line 189, in send
    status = self._verify_status(resp, content)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXX/processes:uno.383135852015228853/connectors/connector_XXX_v1_0.py", line 250, in _verify_status
    jobId=jobReference).execute()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXX/processes:uno.383135852015228853/modules/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXX/processes:uno.383135852015228853/modules/apiclient/http.py", line 676, in execute
    body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXX/processes:uno.383135852015228853/modules/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXX/processes:uno.383135852015228853/modules/oauth2client/client.py", line 490, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXX/processes:uno.383135852015228853/modules/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXX/processes:uno.383135852015228853/modules/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXX/processes:uno.383135852015228853/modules/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1286, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/gae_override/httplib.py", line 536, in getresponse
    'An error occured while connecting to the server: %s' % e)
error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/XXX/jobs/job_d_ONsjBebYjreJuDD-ZdEqCHYv0?alt=json
```

These are from processes fetching data from Google Datastore and loading into BigQuery.

These errors are undeterministic. Sometimes they happen. Sometimes don't. I can't see any pattern here.

One thing to note: up until 2015-05-01 there were no problems with those processes. Data was loaded into BQ without hassle.

My assumption is that it may be somehow related to OAuth2.0. We use

[oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) v1.1. The newest is 1.4.7. Maybe update would help? Or problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: i'm very interesting of the possible answers. We have the exact same problem since the same date.

Comment: is it a timeout issue? try increasing the connect and read timeouts in GAE

Comment: @pinoyyid How can I change connect and read timeouts?

Comment: You can set a deadline for a request, the most amount of time the service will wait for a response. By default, the deadline for a fetch is 5 seconds. The maximum deadline is 60 seconds for HTTP requests and 60 seconds for task queue and cron job requests. When using the URLConnection interface, the service uses the connection timeout (setConnectTimeout()) plus the read timeout (setReadTimeout()) as the deadline.

Comment: @pinoyyid What I didn't mention is we use Python. As far as I can see these methods are available only in Java.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I am having the same issue. I have a 30 second timeout set and I specify num_retries=5 and yet I see this same issue about 10 times a day. When it does fail it does so after 90-800ms. It just says "An error occurred while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: ........"

Comment: we are seeing this too. a great way to get help here is to file a bug report with Google... I did that: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62538081.  Starring it or adding a comment may help us get attention.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize this type of error implement the retry strategy in your application while inserting the Data into the BigQuery. Go through the [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#consistency) for better explaination

Comment: As I can see we have this implemented. 
`getJob = self.jobCollection.get(
                        projectId=self.config['projectId'],
                        jobId=jobReference).execute()` This piece of code is ran about 30 times every 500ms until "Unable to fetch URL:" pops up.